# PowerApp get less alternativ in subcategory when you choose a category

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a problem when i choose the katergoy i get al the subcategory and i just want the subcategory that are matched to the category

[image]

[image]

```
Filter(Möbler; 

Or(IsBlank(DropdownKategori.Selected); 
Kategori.Value = DropdownKategori.Selected.Value

&& 

IsBlank(DropdownSubKategori.Selected); 
SubKategori.Value = DropdownSubKategori.Selected.Value

&& 

IsBlank(DropdownColor.Selected); 
Color.Value = DropdownColor.Selected.Value

&& 

Bokad.Value = "Nej"
)
)
```

Comment: can you please how you are maintaining your categories and subcategories

Comment: And also where you want sub-categories to be filtered as per Category

Comment: Choices(Möbler.Kategori) and Choices(Möbler.SubKategori)